# Generate explanations for each statement in an assembly language program

Tags: assembly, documentation, x86

I'd like to write a script that takes x86 assembly language code as input and generates comments to explain what each statement in the program does. Do tools like this already exist? Also, would this be a relatively simple program to write (since the syntax of each assembly language statement is relatively straightforward?)

Comment: Generating comments that say *what* each statement is doing is relatively straightforward. Generating comments that say *why* the code is doing that would be revolutionary!

Comment: Are you looking for something that (for example) turns `mov rax, rbx` into "Copy the value in register rax into register rbx"?

Comment: @dbaupp, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never heard of one. And I think there's a good reason for that.

If you look at the description of, say, the `int` or `iret` instruction in the CPU documentation, you will see pages of text and pseudo-code.

Most of the regular instruction like `mov` have some tricks up their sleeves too. First, they may have some non-trivial behavior details. Second, they can cause exceptions and fully documenting what happens after an exception takes place is impractical because that depends a lot on the OS and other parts of your program.

So, such a tool would really have a very limited application.

In any case, the best way to learn what every instruction does is to combine reading the CPU documentation with playing with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a program to do this might be a great way to learn assembly language. If you have some existing assembly code and you don't know what it does, sitting down with the relevant assembly reference manual, and some relatively simple string parsing code in your favourite language, would help a lot in learning the assembly instruction set.

You will probably find that only a handful of instruction types make up the bulk of most assembly code. At the assembly level, most of what computers do are: copying data, arithmetic, repetition, and comparisons.